# stuck on autorun python program

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

i tried to make autorun python script and my script is loop forever. Now i stuck on black screen, because i can't exit the python program. I followed this tutorial http://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2013/07/running-a-python-script-at-boot-using-cron/ and in this tutorial didn't including how to exit the program. Can someone tell me how to stop/kill this python program?  :(
i want my desktop back

Comment: Have you tried a keyboard interrupt with CTRL-C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open a terminal (use [Ctrl][Alt][F2] to get to another TTY if you have to)
2. Use `killall` to stop the offensive program. Example: `sudo killall /home/pi/MyScript.py` or `sudo killall /usr/bin/python`
3. Remove the script from your `crontab` by running `sudo crontab -e` and removing the line from your `crontab`
4. Fix your script and test it thoroughly before adding it back to your crontab.

---

If you ***can't*** kill the script with `killall`, you can try:

```
ps aux | grep /home/pi/MyScript.py
```

This will return a line of information about the process, it will show the owner of the process followed by a four digit process id. You can then enter:

```
sudo kill [process id]
```

---

Also, if you used [Ctrl][Alt][F2] to get to another TTY, [Ctrl][Alt][F7] should take you back to your desktop.

Answer (score 0):

in linux or ctr+d
As with the kill and killall commands, pkill is used to send signals to processes. The pkill command allows the use of extended regular expression patterns and other matching criteria